# Arithmetic sequence of exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponential-function

There is an arithmetic sequence $2^a, 3^b, 4^c$ such that a,b and c are positive integers.  The question posed is to find ALL possible ordered triplets $(a,b,c)$.

The constant difference d between the terms allows for a system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns, but properties of the odd and even bases allows deduction of a in the following way:

$3^b - 2^a = d$

$4^c - 3^b = d$

Eliminating d and rearranging gives

$2^{2c-1} + 2^{a-1} = 3^b$

Which can only be true in the cases where a=1 because of the integer clause.  So now what is left is the relationship

$2^{2c-1} + 1 = 3^b$

Which implies that this works for any power of 2 and power of 3 which differ by 1.  I can think of no way to show how to find the pairs 2,3 or 8,9 through any reasoning other than intuition, and thus I don't know how to say that there wouldn't be some unknowingly large pair that would also work.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, our problem is equivalent to: Solve in positive integers:   $$2^{2c-1}+1=3^b$$

$(c,b)=(1,1)$ is a solution. Let $c\ge 2$.

Then mod $4$ gives $b=2m$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$.

$$2^{2c-1}=\left(3^m+1\right)\left(3^m-1\right)$$

LHS is a power of $2$, so $3^m+1$ and $3^m-1$ are both too.

But $\left(3^m+1\right)-\left(3^m-1\right)=2$, so $m=1$.

Answer: $(c,b)=(1,1),(2,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

[Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture) is now Mihăilescu's theorem, so $(8, 9)$ is the only case of adjacent powers for exponents greater than $1$

Comment: Very overkill, but more general of course.

Comment: @user26486 Yes, an oversized hammer, but it was just lying to hand...